# Strange behaviour of random-walk in Python

Tags: python, random-walk

I have a Python dictionary of two-dimensional points, like `points = {1:[0,1],2: [0,0],3: [0,-1]}`.
With each iteration I'm choosing a random point from a dictionary and change it's coordinates (applying random-walk) with the following function:

```
def changecoor(X):
  import random
  return [X[0] + random.choice((-1,1)),X[1] + random.choice((-1,1))]
```

Every five iterations, I'm adding a new point to the dictionary. The code is as follows:

```
points = {1: [0,0]} # creating the first element
for i in range(2000):
  mychoice = random.choice(list(points.keys())) # choosing a random element from the dict
  points[mychoice] = changecoor(points[mychoice]) # applying a function to the chosen element
  if i % 5 == 0:
    points[len(points) + 1] = [0,0]  # Adding new element every 5 loops
```

Now, if I plot my elements on a graph, I expect the element [0,0] to be somewhere in the middle, but it isn't.
The second coordinate is evenly distributed around 0, but I don't have a single point which has the first coordinate negative.

This is an example of what I get:

[image: Not evenly distributed graph]

Comment: Don't put the import inside a function. And yes, as @DarkKnight says, ChatGPT doesn't know everything

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary rather than a list for `points`?

Comment: Also, how do you plot this?

Comment: Please show your plotting code, I'm curious to see how that graph was generated because it looks like your x-axis is the iteration step.  I'm not convinced the graph is showing what you think it shows.

Comment: "I don't have a single point which has the first coordinate negative" - I can't reproduce this. In my testing, I'm getting plenty of points with a negative first coordinate (ca. 150 out of 400 in one run, for example). I suspect your plot is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys :) - for all the answears, I misled you saying, that I didn't get a negative first coordinate, I just didn't check for the values but relied on the wrong graphing method. And you were perfectly right about Chat GPT, but it forced me to ask my first question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Luatic - answering "Why are you using a dictionary rather than a list for points" - a good question, but let me change it: "Why the list of point could be better?" Anyway, at some point you have to: 1) choose a random point, 2) change it - so this is a two step process. Would a list be more efficient than a dictionary?

Comment: @Masdamer yes, both of these are possible with a list. A dict is overkill here, you don't need the hashing. You're effectively using the dict as a list by using keys 1 to n; in Lua this would even be stored as a list :)

Comment: @Luatic - Ok, but its not such a big overkill, is it? You can't just make random.choice(a_list) because you need to have some index of the chosen element, so anyway, you need to choose among indexes, like choosing among the keys.

Comment: @Masdamer you should just use `random.randrange(len(a_list))` for that. Your current `random.choice(list(points.keys()))` is terribly inefficient (linear time).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but your plotting of the results is not correct.

Using your code

```
import random

def changecoor(X):
    return [X[0] + random.choice((-1,1)),X[1] + random.choice((-1,1))]

points = {1: [0,0]} # creating the first element
for i in range(2000):
    mychoice = random.choice(list(points.keys())) # choosing a random element from the dict
    points[mychoice] = changecoor(points[mychoice]) # applying a function to the chosen element
    if i % 5 == 0:
        points[len(points) + 1] = [0,0]  # Adding new element every 5 loops
```

If we take just the values() of the points dictionary and put that into a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(points.values(), columns=['x','y'])
```

Then we do a scatterplot of the x,y values for each point we get a graph of the expected distribution around 0 that you are expecting

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I haven't thought about just such a simple solution, and ofcourse the obvious thing to do (before even asking a question here) was to analyse the points I was getting instead for just looking at the pyplot graph. Thank you very much indeed.